# Remove overlap from vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What basically I am doing is the set cover problem, removing duplicate from the vectors that has the same numbers. An example:

I have the following vectors of vectors after sorting:

```
{{1,2,3,4,5},{2,3,7,8},{10,11,12}}
```

NOW, I would like to remove the occurrence from `2nd` vector which is `2,3` and sort again ...

```
 {{1,2,3,4,5},{10,11,12},{7,8}}
```

I have implemented some code to sort the vectors of vectors but i have problem removing the occurrences from the vector that has less size?

The sort function:

```
sort(ROWS.begin(),ROWS.end(),VectorsSort());
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that telling us you use some functor named `VectorsSort` without showing us the actual implementation of `VectorsSort` isn't useful at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick this apart and take what you need:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct binary_search_pred
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    explicit binary_search_pred(std::vector<int> const& v) : v_(&v) { }

    bool operator ()(int const& i) const
    {
        return std::binary_search(v_->begin(), v_->end(), i);
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> const* v_;
};

struct size_comparison_desc
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    typedef std::vector<int> const& arg_t;
    bool operator ()(arg_t a, arg_t b) const
    {
        return b.size() < a.size();
    }
};

void set_cover(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& vec)
{
    typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > vec_t;
    typedef vec_t::iterator iter_t;
    typedef vec_t::const_iterator citer_t;

    if (vec.empty() || vec.size() == 1)
        return;

    for (iter_t v = vec.begin() + 1, v_end = vec.end(); v != v_end; ++v)
        for (citer_t p = vec.begin(); p != v; ++p)
            v->erase(
                std::remove_if(v->begin(), v->end(), binary_search_pred(*p)),
                v->end()
            );
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), size_comparison_desc());
}
```

(Note that `set_cover` requires that the contained `std::vector<int>`s given **must** already be sorted.)

---

**EDIT #1:**

As requested in now-deleted comments, a version oriented around `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>` instead of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (use `binary_search_pred` from the original code):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

void set_cover(std::map<int, std::vector<int> >& m)
{
    typedef std::map<int, std::vector<int> > map_t;
    typedef map_t::iterator iter_t;
    typedef map_t::const_iterator citer_t;

    if (m.empty() || m.size() == 1)
        return;

    for (iter_t v = ++m.begin(), v_end = m.end(); v != v_end; ++v)
        for (citer_t p = m.begin(); p != v; ++p)
            v->second.erase(
                std::remove_if(
                    v->second.begin(),
                    v->second.end(),
                    binary_search_pred(p->second)
                ),
                v->second.end()
            );
}
```

Note that the `map` here will always be sorted by its key, never by the contained `vector`'s size (which is what you appear to want). Maybe you want a `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>>` instead?

---

**EDIT #2:**

As requested in now-deleted comments, a version oriented around `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>>` instead of `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>` (use `binary_search_pred` from the original code):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct size_comparison_desc
{
    typedef bool result_type;

    typedef std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > const& arg_t;
    bool operator ()(arg_t a, arg_t b) const
    {
        return b.second.size() < a.second.size();
    }
};

void set_cover(std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > >& vec)
{
    typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > > vec_t;
    typedef vec_t::iterator iter_t;
    typedef vec_t::const_iterator citer_t;

    if (vec.empty() || vec.size() == 1)
        return;

    for (iter_t v = vec.begin() + 1, v_end = vec.end(); v != v_end; ++v)
        for (citer_t p = vec.begin(); p != v; ++p)
            v->second.erase(
                std::remove_if(
                    v->second.begin(),
                    v->second.end(),
                    binary_search_pred(p->second)
                ),
                v->second.end()
            );
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), size_comparison_desc());
}
```

Comment: @PALASTINO : Change the algorithm to suit your requirements. That's why I said "*Pick this apart and take what you need*" -- this wasn't intended to be a 100% complete solution, it was only intended to get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't need to define a vector sorting predicate. Vector already defines an `operator<` which is based on `std::lexicographical_compare`.
2. Is this what you mean?

```
std::for_each(rows.begin(), rows.end(), [](std::vector<int>& row) {
    row.erase(std::remove_if(row.begin(), row.end(), [](int number) -> bool {
        return (number == 2) || (number == 3);
    }), row.end());
});
```